# How to show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int \frac{1}{1-t} g(x) dx = \int g(x) dx$

Tags: integration, limits

How to show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1-t} g(x) dx = \int g(x) dx$.

Suppose that $|g(x)|$ is bounded.

I was thinking I should use Dominated Convergence Theorem but how to bound $\frac{1}{1-t}$?

Or this this all an over kill and I can just do this 
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{1-t} g(x) dx\\
&=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{1-t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x) dx \cdot \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{1-t} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x) dx 
\end{align*}

What about the following integral
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{g(x)}{t y(x)+(1-t) h(x)} dx
\end{align*}

Assume that $0<y(x) <c$ and $0< h(x) <c$ and   $\int \frac{g(x)}{ h(x)} dx<a$

\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{g(x)}{t y(x)+(1-t) h(x)} dx \le \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{g(x)}{(1-t) h(x)} dx\\= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{(1-t)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{g(x)}{ h(x)} dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{g(x)}{ h(x)} dx<a
\end{align*}
So, the above say that the integral is finite, but that that mean I can exchange the limits?

Comment: What are the upper and lower limits of the integral? As written right now, $t$ has nothing to do at all with the integral and can just be brought outside.

Comment: Added the limits. That is what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: because the integral deoesn't depend on $t$ the limit is trivial

Comment: I am more interested in the second integral that I just added. Can the limits be exchanged in that one?

Comment: Yes, since the functions don't depend on $t$, the answer is trivial.

Comment: @PaulPicard when you say function doesn't depend on $t$ you mean $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ or you mean $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{ty(x)+(1-t)h(x)}$? Because the second one is?

Comment: I meant the second. The integral is on $x$, so you can calculate the limit of $\frac{g(x)}{ty(x)+(1-t)h(x)}$ before calculating the integral's value. $t$ can be considered as a constant during the integral's calculation. The limit of the integral equals the integral of the limit.